# When perspective division is necessary?

Tags: opengl, 3d, webgl, projection

I'm very confused when it is necessary for a homogeneous coordinate `(x, y, z, w)` get divided by `w` (ie. converting to `(x/w, y/w, z/w, 1)`).

According to this [page](https://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html), when a homogeneous vertex coordinate is passed through a orthographical or projective matrix, the coordinate will be in clip coordinates. Perspective division is necessary for clip coordinates to get NDC. It will produce x, y, and z values in range (-1, 1).

I was following WebGL tutorial pages on [orthographical](http://learnwebgl.brown37.net/08_projections/projections_ortho.html) and [perspective](http://learnwebgl.brown37.net/08_projections/projections_perspective.html) projection. These tutorials didn't mention a single word about perspective division. I'm not sure if the division is still necessary after multiplying with projective matrix. Perhaps, the division is performed automatically during matrix multiplication?

Comment: "*These tutorials didn't mention a single word about perspective division.*" You mean, besides all the words [in this section](http://learnwebgl.brown37.net/08_projections/projections_perspective.html#the-perspective-calculation) where it specifically talks about the perspective divide? It literally says, "*The graphics pipeline is designed to expect the perspective divisor in the w component. The pipeline always calculates (x/w, y/w, z/w) before passing a vertex’s values onto the remaining stages.*"

Comment: Now, I personally don't like some of the language used there, but it does talk about it.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing out. For some reason, I missed this section. I see, I finally got answer to my question: perspective division is necessary after using perspective projection matrix but not necessary for orthographic projection matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perspective divide (the conversion from clip space to NDC space) is neither necessary nor unnecessary; it is a [part of the graphics pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide). It happens automatically to every vertex that passes through the system.

You can make it into a no-op by setting a vertex's W component to 1.0 (which is what the orthographic projection matrix does, assuming the input position had a W of 1.0). But the division always happens.